# What is the image of this Linear Map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In my Linear Algebra class we have been asked to find the kernel and
the image of the following linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$, then verify the rank-nullity theorem.

> $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto(x_1-x_2, x_2-x_3,x_3-x_4,x_4-x_1)$

$\ker(T)$ was trivial, it's obviously equal to the set $\{(v,v,v,v) \mid v \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

However, I am having difficulty finding $\mathrm{im}(T)$. Some observations:

1. There is no ordered 4-tuple in the image such that all four elements have the same sign.
2. $T$ is not surjective, since the vector $(1,0,0,0) \not \in \mathrm{im}(T)$.
3. Since $\{(1,0,0,0), ..., (0,0,0,1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^4$, their images $\{(1,0,0,-1),...,(0,0,-1,1)\}$ must span the image.

Can anyone provide a hint to the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: Let's look at your third point in more detail. You concluded that the images of the four standard basis vectors $$\langle (1, 0, 0, -1)^T, (-1, 1, 0, 0)^T, (0, -1, 1, 0)^T, (0, 0, -1, 1)^T \rangle$$
spans the image. But is this spanning set a *basis* for the image? In other words, is this set linearly independent dependent? If it's independent, we're in trouble with rank-nullity because you found the 1-dimensional kernel. But if it is dependent, how do you modify this set to get a basis?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to narrow down the basis and construct the set.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$1\cdot(1,0,0,-1)^T + 1 \cdot (-1,1,0,0)^T + 1 \cdot (0,-1,1,0)^T + 1 \cdot (0,0,-1,1)^T = \mathbf{0}$, the zero vector.

What happens, if you remove one of those vectors that lie in the span of the other three?